# Laravel makzumi/laravel-calendar get and display multiple diffrent events on date

Tags: php, laravel, calendar

I'm working on an webapp with Laravel, where I keep track of a users workouts, weigh-ins and food intake.

```
Weights
    ID & other data
    Date - YYYY-mm-dd
Workouts
    ID & other data
    Date - YYYY-mm-dd
Intakes
    ID & other data
    Date - YYYY-mm-dd
```

On the users dashboard a calendar is printed using **"makzumi/laravel-calendar"** [located here](https://github.com/makzumi/laravel-calendar). So now to my question, how should I think when trying to get all rows that have been added to this date. So when I look at my calendar, I could see that on the *6th of October* the user have added a Weigh-in, a Workout and Intakes for this date.

So when I begun to populate all the Weigh-ins into the **$events** array like this.

```
$events= array();
        foreach ($calendarWeights as $calWei) {
            $events = array_add($array, $calWei->date, '[Weigh in]');
        }
```

I saw that I could not just add the Workouts and Intakes after this snippet, because then the populated array would have duplicated dates, and the calandar would only show the *[Weigh ins]*. The array is supposed to be constructed in this manner.

```
 $events = array(
        "2014-04-09 10:30:00" => array(
            "Workouts",
            "Intakes",
            "Weights",  
        ),
        "2014-04-12 14:12:23" => array(
            "Intakes",
        ),
        "2014-05-14 08:00:00" => array(
            "Intakes",
        ),
    );
```

But I can't figure out how I am supposed to do this, and any help would be much appriciated. I need someone to point me in the right direction so that I may proceed in the next steps of my webApp. I've also checked for other calendar packages, but not with much result.

**EDIT:** If you know of a better way to get a calendar, my mind is not written in stone about makzumi/laravel-calendar